# How to get purchase link of all songs from itunes

Tags: itunes

I am working on an music app by using which we can listen,buy(iTunes),share the songs but I have no idea how to get the purchase link of songs. I'm using 
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=let+it+go&media=music
to get information but the purchase link not provide in it.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that to redirect to an album page the URL are like this: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id{collectionId}`, with `{collectionId}` provided by the search API.

Now I think that to get a certain song the URL would be: `https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id{collectionId}?i={trackId}`.

Example: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/id728903889?i=728904065 for the song *"Let it go"*, by *Demi Lovato*.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the track is provided in each result's `trackViewUrl`.

For example, the first `trackViewUrl` in the file you provided is https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/let-it-go/id948749743?i=948749751&uo=4